# Why is adding parentheses to a filter in 'jq' producing valid JSON and without parentheses, multiple outputs of objects?

Tags: json, command-line, jq

With [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), I would like to set a property within JSON data and let [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) output the original JSON with the updated value. I found, more or less due to trial and error, a solution, and want to understand why and how it works.

I have the following JSON data:

```json
{
    "notifications": [
    {
      "source": "observer01",
      "channel": "error",
      "time": "2021-01-01 01:01:01"
    },
    {
      "source": "observer01",
      "channel": "info",
      "time": "2021-02-02 02:02:02"
    }
  ]
}
```

My goal is to update the `time` property of an object with a specific `source` and `channel` (the original JSON is way longer with lots of objects in the `notifications` array of the same format).

(In the following example, I want to update the `time` property of `observer01` with channel `info`, so the second object in the example data above.)

My first try, not producing the desired output, was the following `jq` command:

```
jq '.notifications[] | select(.source == "observer01" and .channel == "info").time = "NEWTIME"' data.json
```

That produces the following output:

```json
{
  "source": "observer01",
  "channel": "error",
  "time": "2021-01-01 01:01:01"
},
{
  "source": "observer01",
  "channel": "info",
  "time": "NEWTIME"
}
```

Which is just a list of the JSON objects within the `notifications` array. I understand that this can be useful, for example piping the objects to other command line tools.

Now let's try the following `jq` command, which is the same as above plus one pair of parentheses:

```
jq '(.notifications[] | select(.source == "observer01" and .channel == "info").time) = "NEWTIME"' data.json
```

This produces the desired output, the original valid JSON with the updated `time` property:

```json
{
    "notifications": [
    {
      "source": "observer01",
      "channel": "error",
      "time": "2021-01-01 01:01:01"
    },
    {
      "source": "observer01",
      "channel": "info",
      "time": "NEWTIME"
    }
  ]
}
```

Why is adding the parentheses to the `jq` filter in the case above producing a different output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's compare the two.

```
 .notifications[] | select(...).time = "NEWTIME"

(.notifications[] | select(...).time) = "NEWTIME"
```

In the first one, the top-level filter is defined by `|`. The input is an object, and the output is the result of applying `select(...).time = "NEWTIME"` to each value produced by `.notifications[]`. In essence, the original object is "lost".

In the second one, the top-level filter is defined by `=`. `x = y` returns its input as output, but with a side effect produced by

1. Determining what the *path expression* `x` refers to in the input,
2. Evaluating the *filter* `y` on the input, (Even an expression like `"NEWTIME"` is just a filter: one that ignores its input and returns the string `"NEWTIME"`)
3. Assigning the result of `y` to the thing addressed by `x`.

Comment: +1 Thank you @chepner! While @choroba also made an excellent post, I choose yours as the accepted answer, because you gave some really helpful in-depth explanations.

Answer (score 4):

The parentheses just change the precedence. It's documented in `man jq`:

> Parenthesis work as a grouping operator just as in any  typical  programming  language.
>
> ```
>       jq ´(. + 2) * 5´
>          1
>       => 15
> ```

Let's have a simpler example:

```
echo '[{"a":1}, {"a":2}]' | jq '.[] | .a |= .+1'
```

It outputs

```
{
  "a": 2
}
{
  "a": 3
}
```

because it's interpreted as

```
                                      ↓         ↓
echo '[{"a":1}, {"a":2}]' | jq '.[] | (.a |= .+1)'
```

The first filter `.[]` outputs the elements as separated objects, they are then modified by the second filter.

Placing the parentheses after the first two elements changes the precedence:

```
                                ↓        ↓
echo '[{"a":1}, {"a":2}]' | jq '(.[] | .a) |= .+1'
```

and produces a different otuput:

```
[
  {
    "a": 2
  },
  {
    "a": 3
  }
]
```

BTW, this is the same output as from

```
echo '[{"a":1}, {"a":2}]' | jq '.[].a |= .+1'
```

It changes the value associated with the `"a"` key in the array.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot for your explanation @choroba, your examples helped me get an understanding what difference those parentheses make.